# Backbone and Jasmine - The context of a Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, bdd

Let's say I have a unit of table row, which contains details about some basketball team (games, won, lost, etc.) who plays in a league.

Now I want to write unit tests.

Which one of the following approaches is **a better use-case**:

### Approach 1: Technical

Treat the unit as a **table row.**:

```
describe("Given a table row", function(){
    describe("When I remove it from the table", function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

### Approach 2: Practical

Treat the unit as a **basketball team.**:

```
describe("Given a basketball team", function(){
    describe("When I remove it from the league", function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I would say the technical one as it's more reusable and less tied to the specific domain of your app

Answer (score 2):

The language of your tests should be in the same domain as your classes.

In other words, approach 2 is best because in a [Behavior Driven Development](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) sense you are expressing behaviors.

You should also try to use user story-like language in acceptance tests.

`When a Coach removes it from the league`